# Remove @{ColumnName from Powershell results

Tags: powershell

I'm relatively new to PowerShell scripting and have mainly been cobbling together different scripts and cmdlets from Googling what I'm trying to do. One problem that I'm unable to Google, or search for on StackExchange, because of the special characters is having all my results come out as @{ColumnName=ColumnData}.

Here's an example script I found somewhere for pulling all the members of an AD group.

```
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like "!GroupName"}
$path = $groups
$myCol = @()
ForEach ($Group in $Groups)
{
    $Members = @(Get-ADGroupMember "$Group")
    ForEach ($Member in $Members){
       try{
        $user = get-aduser -identity $member -properties displayname
        $MyObject = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Displayname = $user.Displayname
       }        
        $mycol += $MyObject}
catch {}}
    }
Write-Host $MyCol | FL
```

I'm pretty sure there are better ways to get the members of an AD group but that's not the issue at the moment. The problem is all the data comes out like @{Displayname=Lawrence, Kimberly} and this happens with many of the scripts I've thrown together.

Any ideas on how to write scripts properly so I can just get DisplayName = Lawrence, Kimberly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree your code is complex and it does not need to be. A couple of things that are important to mention is *why* your output looks the way it does.

You are creating an array of `PSCustomObject`s which function similar to hash-tables. In the end of your processing you have an array of objects with the property `DisplayName`. Since you are using `Write-Host` to display the the contents of `$myCol` it needs to cast it a string array in order to display it. You would see similar output if you just typed `[string[]]$myCol`. I should hope that you are doing something else in the processing as like the other answers show you have a very complicated way of getting what you are looking for.

Without beating the horse about those other solutions I will suggest some minor changes to yours as it stands. Your title and last sentence contradict what you are looking for since you want to remove the ColumnName in the title and the last sentence you are looking for output like `DisplayName = Name`.

Changing the last line will address both of these. If you just want the `displayname`s on there own

```
$myCols | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayName

Lawrence, Kimberly
```

and if you actually want the other format you could do this

```
$myCols | ForEach-Object{
    "DisplayName = $($_.DisplayName)"
}
```

Again, like the other answers, I stress that your code could use simple overhaul. If you needed to understand why it was working the way it way I hope I helped a little.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the PSCustomObjects and hash-tables. Since I've encountered this problem with a variety of scripts, your answer is the information I'm looking for more than solving this particular bit of code.

Is it just a matter of using write-host that prevents these from displaying the way I want or do I need to store the data in a different way before displaying it?

Comment: @user2516896 `Write-Host` is great for basic string and colouring. If you have object and you want to _display_ information on the screen piping into one of the `Format-` cmdlets could help. `$MyCol | FL` on its own could work. Outside of that it boils down to need and preference. One size does not fit all.

Answer (score 0):

This actually has nothing to do with Active Directory;  You are creating custom objects, then outputting them directly, and by default that is how PowerShell will format the output if you use Write-Host (which is intended to customize output).  If you would like to be more specific about what your output should look like, we can help, but here is an example that outputs the results as just a list of strings, just using Write-Output:

```
$myCol = @()
$MyObject = New-Object PSObject -Property @{ DisplayName = "Lawrence, Kimberly" }
$myCol += $MyObject
$MyObject = New-Object PSObject -Property @{ DisplayName = "Hello, World" }
$myCol += $MyObject

# The default will show at-symbols, etc:  Write-Host $MyCol | FL

Write-Output $myCol
```

The output will be:

```
DisplayName                                                                                                                                                           
-----------                                                                                                                                                           
Lawrence, Kimberly                                                                                                                                                    
Hello, World
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like '!GroupName'" | 
  Get-ADGroupMember | 
  Get-ADUser -Properties DisplayName | 
  Select-Object DisplayName
```

When I ran your code, I also got the hashes, even without special characters. Your code is way too unnecessarily complex.