# Using PowerShell, How to get list of all Azure subscriptions having Azure Data factory Resource in it?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I want to retrieve the list of subscriptions having Azure Data Factory resource in it. I want to use PowerShell and get the subscription list and ADF list.

I have tried `Get-AzSubscription`, but it does not contain filter for resource type i.e. `Microsoft.DataFactory/factories`. This filter can be added to only `Get-AzResource`.

1. [Get-AzSubscription Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/get-azsubscription?view=azps-6.0.0#examples)
2. [Get-AzResource Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresource?view=azps-6.0.0#examples)

Comment: Hello! Do you already have something to start with? Anything that you already tried, that someone can help add on to?

Comment: @Ked - updated the Question details section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here you are:

```
$resType     = "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories"
$resTypeName = "DataFactory"
Get-AzSubscription | ForEach-Object {
    $subscriptionName = $_.Name
    $tenantId = $_.TenantId
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $_.SubscriptionId -TenantId $_.TenantId
    (Get-AzResource -ResourceType $ResType) | ForEach-Object {     
        [PSCustomObject] @{
            true_sub = $subscriptionName
        } 
    } | get-unique 
} | Select-String 'true_sub' | ForEach-Object{ "Found_" + "$resTypeName" + "_In_Subscription= $($subscriptionName)"}
```

EDIT: Added variables to make it easily reusable for any resource type.

I used the code available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61680135/16046045) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28422212/16046045) to create a custom one based on the requirements. Tested in my environment - it seems to work as expected.

I should disclose that I'm not an advanced PowerShell user, so the code I'm providing could really be sub-optimal.

Comment: This worked for me. But just would like to check if there is any other optimized way.

Comment: If you're using Azure Resource Graph Explorer then it's quite easy since it gives you a way to query all your subscription easily. For powershell, the azure context matters - that's the issue. If you wanted to query a different subscription, you'd really need to change your context to a different subscription

Comment: Ok. I will explore more on Azure Resource Graph. Thank you for the solution.